# Running java by arguments in Docker

Tags: java, docker

Let's say we have the following Dockerfile for the purpose of creating a java image and compiling two scripts.

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY src JavaDocker
WORKDIR JavaDocker
RUN mkdir -p bin
RUN javac -d bin ./com/myapp/HelloWorld1.java
RUN javac -d bin ./com/myapp/HelloWorld2.java
WORKDIR bin
ENTRYPOINT java
```

How can I run any of these two scripts that have been compiled?

I'm using the command: `docker run myapp-image "com.myapp.Server"`

And I get:

```
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)

 Arguments following the main class, source file, -jar <jarfile>,
 -m or --module <module>/<mainclass> are passed as the arguments to
 main class.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building a separate image per application; that can help clarify what the image is supposed to do.  I also generally recommend using `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT`.

So a Dockerfile that runs only the first application could look like:

```sh
FROM openjdk:latest

# Prefer an absolute path for clarity.
WORKDIR /JavaDocker

# Set up the Java class path.
RUN mkdir bin
ENV CLASSPATH=/JavaDocker/bin

# Use a relative path as the target, to avoid repeating it.
# (If you change the source code, repeating `docker build` will
# skip everything before here.)
COPY src .

# Compile the application.
RUN javac -d bin ./com/myapp/HelloWorld1.java

# Set the main container command.
CMD ["java", "com.myapp.HelloWorld1"]
```

What if you do have an image that contains multiple applications?  If you use `CMD` here, it's very easy to provide an alternate command when you run the image:

```sh
docker run myapp-image \
  java com.myapp.HelloWorld2

# Wait, what's actually in this image?
docker run --rm myapp-image \
  ls -l bin/com/myapp
```

I generally recommend reserving `ENTRYPOINT` for a wrapper script that does some first-time setup, then runs `exec "$@"` to run a normal `CMD`.  There's an alternate pattern of giving a *complete* command in `ENTRYPOINT`, and using `CMD` to provide its arguments.  In both of these cases `ENTRYPOINT` needs to be JSON-array syntax, not shell syntax.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "com.myapp.HelloWorld1"] # <-- JSON-array syntax
CMD ["-argument", "to-program-1"]
```

```sh
docker run myapp-image \
  -argument=different -options
```

but it's harder to make that image do something else

```sh
docker run \
  --entrypoint ls \ # <-- first word of the command is before the image name
  myapp-image \
  -l bin/com/myapp  # <-- and the rest after

docker run \
  --entrypoint java \
  myapp-image \
  com.myapp.HelloWorld2
```

Your original Dockerfile will probably work if you change the `ENTRYPOINT` line from shell to JSON-array syntax; using shell syntax will cause the `CMD` part to be ignored (including a command passed after the `docker run image-name`).  You might find it easier to make one complete application invocation be the default and include the `java` command if you need to run the other.